# How do I delegate Jquery UI click from image to list item?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, jquery-ui

I have a UL that contains items that the user can click on and move from one list to another.  I have a function to inspect the list item and move it from one list to another and it works well -- except for one problem.

The list item contains an image (which also responds to the click event).  So if my user clicks on the image (essentially a + or - sign that represents add/remove) the function does not work, as the element that it expected as the target is the image, not the list item.  How can I delegate the image click to the li that contains it?

The list item is built using struts2 iterator

```
        <li class="ui-widget-content" id="<s:property value="userId"/>">
            <img src="/images/add_16.png" border="0" alt="add"/>
            <s:property value="firstName"/>&nbsp;<s:property value="lastName"/>
        </li>
```

I tried this...

```
$("#ul-available li").delegate("img", "click", function(){
        $(this).click();
    });
```

...thinking that if I click the image I could simply invoke the click event on the list item, but it doesn't work.  Any ideas what I am doing wrong, or any other ideas on how to accomplish this would be much appreciated.

Thanks to any/all replies!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) `this` is referring to the `<img>` still, you need to crawl up to the `<li>`...using [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) is a good method, like this:

```
$("#ul-available").delegate("li img", "click", function(){
  $(this).closest("li").click();
});
```

[`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) is also intended to capture clicks, so it's better up on the `<ul>` instead of on each `<li>`, I've made this adjustment above.

Comment: That does it. I also tried $(this).parent().click() which also seems to work. How do I keep the click event from continuing? The event fires twice, once for the actual click and once for the click I invoke on the list item...

Comment: @Griff - If you don't want it, you can add a `return false;` at the end to stop the other event bubble :)

Comment: Crap. That makes sense. Although, if I understood you correctly, it's not working.    $("#ul-available").delegate("li img", "click", function(){
          $(this).closest("li").click();
          return false;
    });

Comment: @Griff - Try this instead (though it's hard to know without seeing your other function):  `$("#ul-available li img").click(function(){ $(this).closest("li").click(); return false; });`